# columns equal to something in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am interested in how to write mysql query like this => if some column includes multiple exactly same data, how to check if that column value equal to something . for example I have table with column named "local" and I'm checking like that =>

```
SELECT (IF(SELECT local FROM database WHERE local='something'),"Equal","NOT Equal");
```

This gives me error => **ERROR 1242 (21000) Subquery returns more than 1 row**

How to write this checking code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT (IF EXISTS (SELECT local FROM database WHERE local='something'),"Equal","NOT Equal");
```

Comment: this checks first value from table yes ?

Comment: p.s. I switched it back to TOP(1) I got confused for a second, but it's back to TOP(1) after I re-read it

Comment: result is the same (error) ? this TOP() must be a function, maybe you have declared top() like function because , I have tried like you wrote and it gives me result FUNCTION table.top does not exists

Comment: @DaHaKa and back to EXISTS it is, give it a try :D

Answer (score 0):

```
select local from database where local in('something','equal','not equal');
```